# Python loop same result for list of lists and comma separated lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I've recently come across this behavior in python by accident. Could someone explain why looping through a `list of lists` as well as a comma separated lists result in the same result.

```
# comma separated lists
values = ['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish']
for v in values:
    print(v)

# List of lists
values = [['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish']]
for v in values:
    print(v)
```

Comment: because values is assumed to be a `tuple` in the first case and you can loop through a tuple of lists in the same way as you loop through a list of lists. just `print(type(values))` and you shall see.

Comment: `print(values)` in each case - you'll see the first creates a tuple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you comma separate values, Python **interprets this as a tuple**. So your first statement is equivalent to:

```
values = (['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish'])
```

Like a list, a tuple is iterable over its elements (which are again `['cat','fish']`, etc.)

so for the `v` in the `for` loop, nothing changes.

The only difference is that a tuple is **immutable**, so you **cannot add/remove** elements to the first `values`, nor can you *set* the elements of `values` (you can however perform calls on the individual lists).

Comment: Thank you Williem Van Onsem !

Answer (score 6):

the comma separated lists is in fact a tuple:

```
>>> values = ['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish']
>>> values
(['cat', 'fish'], ['cat', 'fish', 'monkey'], ['cat', 'fish', 'monkey', 'fish'])
>>> type(values)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Since tuples are iterable, you get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, when separating the lists by comas you are building a tuple, wich can be iterated:

```
values = ['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish']
values
(['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], ['cat','fish','monkey','fish'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First one treated as a tuple and second one is the list. Both are iterable over for loop.

```
    # comma separated lists
    values = ['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'],['cat','fish','monkey','fish']
    print(type(values))
    # Output will be <type 'tuple'>

    # List of lists
    values = [['cat','fish'], ['cat','fish','monkey'], `enter code here`['cat','fish','monkey','fish']]
     print(type(values))
    # Output will be <type 'list'>
```